# Ajax Load More Product showing in Single Column

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have an issue with ajax load more function. I am using WooCommerce Ajax Load More Products by connekthq.
hey, I have a woocommerce website just install the ajax load more Plugin after adding the shortcode to my website, Products are not showing in columns only 1 products not showing in 4 columns Grid
**Here is code I used in Repeater Templates**

```html
<?php
global $woocommerce_loop; 

if( isset($columns) && !empty($columns) ) {
    $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $columns;
}

$product_item = isset($product_item) ? $product_item : 'inner';

$screen_desktop          =      isset($screen_desktop) ? $screen_desktop : 4;
$screen_desktopsmall     =      isset($screen_desktopsmall) ? $screen_desktopsmall : 3;
$screen_tablet           =      isset($screen_tablet) ? $screen_tablet : 3;
$screen_mobile           =      isset($screen_mobile) ? $screen_mobile : 1;

$count = 0;

if( isset($attr_row) && !empty($attr_row) ) {
    $class = 'products products-grid';
} else {
    $data_responsive = '';
    $data_responsive .= ' data-xlgdesktop='. $columns .'';
    $data_responsive .= ' data-desktop='. $screen_desktop .'';
    $data_responsive .= ' data-desktopsmall='. $screen_desktopsmall .'';
    $data_responsive .= ' data-tablet='. $screen_tablet .'';
    $data_responsive .= ' data-mobile='. $screen_mobile .''; 
    $class = ($columns <= 1) ? 'w-products-list' : 'products products-grid';
}
?>
<div class="products products-grid">
<div class="row grid" data-xlgdesktop=4 data-desktop=4 data-desktopsmall=4 data-tablet=2 data-mobile=2>
<?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>
</div>
```

**And Here is My Theme Grid code**

```html
<?php
global $woocommerce_loop; 

if( isset($columns) && !empty($columns) ) {
    $woocommerce_loop['columns'] = $columns;
}

$product_item = isset($product_item) ? $product_item : 'inner';

$screen_desktop          =      isset($screen_desktop) ? $screen_desktop : 4;
$screen_desktopsmall     =      isset($screen_desktopsmall) ? $screen_desktopsmall : 3;
$screen_tablet           =      isset($screen_tablet) ? $screen_tablet : 3;
$screen_mobile           =      isset($screen_mobile) ? $screen_mobile : 1;

$count = 0;

if( isset($attr_row) && !empty($attr_row) ) {
    $class = 'products products-grid';
} else {
    $data_responsive = '';
    $data_responsive .= ' data-xlgdesktop='. $columns .'';
    $data_responsive .= ' data-desktop='. $screen_desktop .'';
    $data_responsive .= ' data-desktopsmall='. $screen_desktopsmall .'';
    $data_responsive .= ' data-tablet='. $screen_tablet .'';
    $data_responsive .= ' data-mobile='. $screen_mobile .''; 
    $class = ($columns <= 1) ? 'w-products-list' : 'products products-grid';
}
?>
<div class="<?php echo esc_attr( $class ); ?>">

    <?php if( isset($attr_row) && !empty($attr_row) ) : ?>
        <div <?php echo trim($attr_row); ?>>
    <?php else : ?>
        <div class="row grid" <?php echo esc_attr($data_responsive); ?>>
    <?php endif; ?>

        <?php while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>

            <?php 
                $post_object = get_post( get_the_ID() );
                setup_postdata( $GLOBALS['post'] =& $post_object );
                
                wc_get_template( 'content-products.php', array('product_item' => $product_item,'screen_desktop' => $screen_desktop,'screen_desktopsmall' => $screen_desktopsmall,'screen_tablet' => $screen_tablet,'screen_mobile' => $screen_mobile) ); 
            ?>

            <?php $count++; ?>

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

How to fix repeater templates code